# C++14: can you call new in a constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

When C++14 lifted restrictions on `constexpr` it seemed to include the following (copied from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++14#Relaxed_constexpr_restrictions)):

> Expressions may change the value of an object if the lifetime of that
>   object began within the constant expression function. This includes
>   calls to any non-const constexpr-declared non-static member functions.

That seems to imply that you could create an object using `new` and as long as you `delete` it within the expression, then it would be allowed.

Comment: in c++14, no. in c++20, yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Language lawyer answer. All references to [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf).

7.1.5/5 states:

> For a non-template, non-defaulted `constexpr` function or a non-template, non-defaulted, non-inheriting `constexpr` constructor, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated  subexpression of a core constant expression (5.19), the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Jumping over to 5.19, we see:

> A *conditional-expression* `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - ... [lots of bullets]...
> - a *new-expression* (5.3.4);
> - a *delete-expression* (5.3.5);
> - ... [lots more bullets]...

So no: a program containing a `constexpr` function with an unconditional invocation of `new` or `delete` in it is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. (I'd be surprised, however, if any half-decent compiler failed to diagnose such invocations of `new` or `delete` in a `constexpr` function, required or not.)

Comment: *I'd be surprised, however, if any half-decent compiler failed to diagnose instances of new or delete in a constexpr function, required or not.* It's not a problem to have a `new` or `delete` in a constexpr function. This one for example is perfectly legal (although silly) `constexpr int f(int a) { return a ? a : *new int(0); }` As long as called with non-zero ints, we are fine. No diagnostic is required and the code is ill-formed for the case where for *all function arguments* the `new` will be evaluated.

Comment: update, year 2018: both clang and gcc still silently accept buggy code....

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. You are still limited to calling other `constexpr` functions. `new` is actually a function call to `operator new()` which is not a `constexpr` function. The same goes for `delete`.

Comment: A call to `operator new()` is one of several effects of using the `new` operator.  (Another important effect is running the object constructor).  Ditto `delete`, which calls the destructor before the deallocation function.