# Return object from constexpr?

Tags: c++, static, constexpr

How do I return an object from a constexpr function? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897015/c14-can-you-call-new-in-a-constexpr) you can't use `new` but how do I do it then? Is it possible at all? I want to use the argument of the function to intialize an object and return it, but can't seem to figure out how.

Example:

```
struct Test {
    int a;
    constexpr Test (int b): a(b) {};
    Test(const Test& a);
};

Test::Test(const Test& t) {
    this->a = t.a;
}

constexpr Test set_test(int a) {
    return Test(a);
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do your thoughts jump to `new` right away?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? *Why* do you want to use `constexpr` functions and `new`? This is an [XY-problem question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Well otherwise it would allocated on the stack and not survive after the function.

Comment: A function can return an object by value.

Comment: _not survive after the function_ if you don't return a pointer/reference that's not a problem.

Comment: What do you mean by _object_? A class instance?

Comment: You're right, but If I return an object the compiler say: ```error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression``` even though the constructor is constexpr.

Comment: In that case show us a minimal example which reproduces your error.

Comment: Operator `new` is radioactive. It must only be handled by experts who are trained in how to encase it in concrete and lead. I have been programming in C++ since cfront (1984), and I think I have used `new' just once since C++98. That was in writing a custom allocator.

Comment: *"f I return an object the compiler say: error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression even though the constructor is constexpr"* - I can't see it. Until humans develop telepathy, could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] as trying to guess the right answer to invisible code is not working for us.

Comment: If we are going to help, we gots to have a [MCVE].

Comment: Will try to fix one.

Comment: Added example code.

Comment: @JiveDadson and there was me thinking that your use of new was in conjunction with other descriptors like `newConnection()`meaning you weren't even using the keyword! :)

Comment: So, what's wrong with the code? I copy/pasted it in [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/1BZhTp). It compiles and works. (Only, that I added output to prevent optimization.)

Comment: The example you give compiles but does nothing. Post an example that demonstrates what you are trying to do, and what it actually does instead. It is not even clear to me why you want to define the function as constexpr.

Comment: I get the compile error specified above in clang with ```-std=c++11``` flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a small addition to the exposed sample code to make use of `set_test()` and to prevent optimization of dead code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
    int a;
    constexpr Test (int b): a(b) {};
    Test(const Test& a);
};

Test::Test(const Test& t) {
    this->a = t.a;
}

constexpr Test set_test(int a) {
    return Test(a);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "set_test(1).a: " << set_test(1).a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine in [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/1BZhTp).

It states to use `C++ (gcc 6.3)`.

Hence, I was looking for another online compile where I can choose `clang` and found [**Wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/).

With `clang HEAD 7.0.0` it fails to compile. If I got it right `set_test()` tries to use the copy constructor which is not `constexpr`.

Thus, I `delete`d the copy constructor. Now, it fails in `return Test(a);` because it tries to access the deleted copy constructor. Strange...

So, I finally provided a move-constructor

`constexpr Test(Test &&test): a(test.a) { }`

as replacement for the deleted copy constructor. Now, it compiles and works:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
    int a;
    constexpr Test (int b): a(b) {}
    Test(const Test& a) = delete;
    constexpr Test(Test &&test): a(test.a) { }
};

#if 0
Test::Test(const Test& t) {
    this->a = t.a;
}
#endif // 0

constexpr Test set_test(int a) {
    return Test(a);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "set_test(1).a: " << set_test(1).a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Start

set_test(1).a: 1

0

Finish
```

Life demo on [**Wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zwgIf7npjRBuDZfM).

---

Out of curiosity, I modified the sample again to try out if making the copy-constructor a `constexpr` would fix as well. It does.

Life demo on [**Wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aYp1WxAe3yBtpRBQ).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a parameterized `constexpr` function of some type `T` returning a value of type `T`, `T` being a user defined class. Simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
private:
    int x;
public:
    constexpr A(int x) : x(x) {};
    void print() {
        std::cout << x;
    }
};

constexpr A foo(int p) {
    A temp{ p };
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    A o = foo(123);
    o.print();
}
```

The whole point of the `constexpr` function is that its return type satisfies the  [constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) requirements.

Comment: Shouldn't the constructor be declared `constexpr`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Indeed so. Updated.